# Summing and saving the values of column based on other column pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

df1 =

```
A        B
61880    7
62646    8
62651    9
62656    10
62783    11
61880    3
62646    2
```

I want to do `data.groupby('A')['B'].sum()` but in the way to save the result of "B" as a new column "B_updated" based on values of "A"

After `data.groupby('A')['B'].sum()` my output is:

```
A        B
61880    10
62646    10
...
```

It is good, but I can not perform further operations. Thus, I want to save "B" wrt "A". Because my next operation will be [Math operations of column based on same values of other column pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55745057/math-operations-of-column-based-on-same-values-of-other-column-pandas)

Comment: you mean `df['B_updated']=df.groupby('A')['B'].transform('sum')` ??

Comment: can you post the desired output please? or do you just require `data.groupby('A')['B'].sum().reset_index()`

Comment: @NazarTarlanli: Did you set the column or just run the right hand side of anky_91's solution? The indices will match up as you expect.

Comment: @anky_91 , seems good! I need to check and will inform in a comment! Thanks!

Comment: @fuglede, yes! I got a bit confused. Seems everything is working! I`m checking now

Comment: `df['new_B'] = df.groupby(by=['A'])['B'].transform(sum)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
x_df = df.groupby('A').size().reset_index(name='B_updated')
print(x_df)
```